# Creating a marketing front for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, content-management-system

I started to get comfortable with Rails and programming in general. I'm working on a Rails app with basic authorization and authentication. I wish to have a CMS for the landing page, while the core functionality of the website would be in Rails. I've seen that it's very useful to separate the marketing assets from the core app for iterating on the messaging and other content.

My plan is for the landing page to have 3 fields for the signup- `Username`, `email` and `password`, for new users to fill in, which should then be stored in the database and used by the Rails app behind the landing page. I'm thinking of using Wordpress to do so, simply because that's the only CMS I'm comfortable with.

I was wondering how I should go about this? Is this recommended, and if so, would the necessary way to go about it be a Wordpress plugin? (I couldn't narrow it down to a good Rails plugin, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated) . Are there any alternatives to plugins? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why not using devise gem? Everyone uses that. Its well tested and has tons of useful features. And if its a small app, your own created authentication system might be enough.

And for CMS I would like Wordpress for SEO purposes, and Rails Frog for ease of use

Comment: I will be using devise. My app currently has a landing page on Rails iteself. What I want to do is have a landing page on a CMS. It doesn't even have to have form fields, just information. What I could do is just have 2 buttons - `login` and `signup` , which redirects into the Rails app.

Comment: There are numbers of ways to do that. If you need some functionality between them, dealing deeper with API's would be necessary. Try google "rails and wordpress on the same domain". And check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89504/whats-the-best-way-to-run-wordpress-on-the-same-domain-as-a-rails-application

Answer (score 1):

You could use Refinery CMS with or without the Rest API:

- http://www.refinerycms.com/
- http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app
- https://github.com/refinerycms-contrib/refinerycms-api